# Replace a value at the end of a string converted to an array in one line?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to replace the last item in array with one line of code?

What I receive:

```
return "my.long.string";
```

What I want:

```
return "my.long.output";
```

Code so far:

```
var value = "my.long.string";
var newValue = value.split(".").pop().join(".") + "output";
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

**Update:**

Nina answered it. I also had a case where I need to insert a value at the end of the string (add in a name to a file path). It's the same as above but replaces everything right *before* the last dot.

```
var value = "my.long.string";
var result = value.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".") + "_stats." + "output";
```

Comment: pop is going to return the popped element of the array not the modified array, probably want to do a slice(0,-1) which returns a new array without the last element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could slice the array and concat the last string. [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes negative values for offsets from the end of the array.

```js
var value = "my.long.string";

value = value.split('.').slice(0, -1).concat('output').join('.');

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

You also don't have to convert it into an array. You could use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) like so:

```js
const value = "my.long.string";

console.log(`${value.substring(0,value.lastIndexOf('.'))}.output`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex `(.*\.).*` to capture everything up until the final `.` and `replace` the last part with the new string ([Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5EzGu/1/)). [`$1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) gets the string from the capture group

```js
let str = "my.long.string"
let newStr = str.replace(/(.*\.).*/, `$1output`);
console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "my.long.string";
var newValue = value.split('.').filter((val, idx, arr) => {
    return idx < arr.length - 1
}).concat('output').join('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution

```js
var value = "my.long.string";
var newValue = value.split('.').splice(0, value.match(/\./g).length).concat('output').join('.');
console.log(newValue);
```

Second solution (shorter)

```js
var value = "my.long.string";
var newValue = value.split('.').fill('output', value.match(/\./g).length).join('.');
console.log(newValue);
```

Comment: `splice(0, 2)` assumes # of dots is known , probably isn't

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, I removed and left only the solutions for any # of dots

Answer (score -1):

following code you can try.

```
var value = "my.long.string";
var newValue = value.replace(new RegExp(value.split(".").pop() + '$'), "output");
```

Comment: Will fail with if that last substring exists elsewhere .... `"my.long.string.long.string"`

Comment: @charlietfl but OP wants to replace only the last item with `"output"`

Comment: Yes but `pop()` will return "string" and `replace()` will replace first instance . Try it

Comment: I just edited my code to replace only last element of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
var value = "my.long.string";
var r = value.split(".").splice(-1, 1).join(".");
var result = r.".output";
```